# Compositing results in a black screen, even if output is hooked up

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

I've got a render which displays as intended when I turn compositing off, but shows a black screen when compositing is turned on in my render settings. I've attached a screenshot of the graph. I think everything is set up right, as the image I'm viewing is the same image being passed into the compositor. I could be wrong. Any help is appreciated :)

[image]

Comment: And the rendered image file is indeed black not transparent?

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard yeah when I check the composition option in the post processing settings the rendered video is black. I tried rendering with images as well and they’re also black. When composition is unchecked everything works fine. Just for reference I’ve got sequencing unchecked as well in post processing.